# Get ID of currently running standalone script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to get the ID of the currently running standalone apps script? I'm needing to check if the currently logged in user is the owner of the script before running certain functions in this web app. I need to keep the overall accessibility to everyone, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just found [this in the Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getScriptId()).

```js
var script_id = ScriptApp.getScriptId()
```